# Property 'locals' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: node.js, typescript, restify

I want to use `res.locals` to pass some data between middlewares but typescript says I can't. :(

I am using [Restify](http://restify.com/) by the way. Do I need a plugin?
If not, an alternative solution for passing data between middlewares would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

⚠️ If you use typescript, then you get an error, because `locals` is not part of Interface res.

So, if you want to add your own property, for example in res, then you can make it like this: `res['locals'] = { name: 'John doe' }`.

**Update: Add properties to restify `res`**

To declare `locals` properties to your restify`Response`, than you can use the code below:

```js
declare module 'restify' {
  interface Response{
    locals: any
  }
}
```

**After you declare your own properties**, An example `locals` in your Restify Response, so, now you can use `locals` in your restify`response`.